# Facing NullPointerException in Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have created three files: one is index file, other is configuration file and last the last one is the property file. While executing the code I'm getting `NULLPointerException`.

I am not able to solve this issue. Please help me to rectify this code.

`index.java`:

```
package main;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import config.Configuration;

public class Index 
{
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void handling_multiple_windows() throws Exception
    {
        Configuration obj = new Configuration();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", obj.path());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(obj.handling_window_url());
    }
}
```

`Configuration.java`:

```
package config;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Configuration 
{
    Properties pro;
    WebDriver driver;
    public Configuration() throws Exception
    {
        File f = new File("./Config/config.property");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        Properties pro = new Properties();
        pro.load(fis);  
    }   

    public String path()
    {
        String url = pro.getProperty("ChromeDriverPath");
        return url;
    }

    public String handling_window_url()
    {
        return pro.getProperty("URL");
    }
}
```

`config.property`:

```
ChromeDriverPath = G:\\Selenium Webdriver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe
URL = https://www.naukri.com
```

Comment: Where are you getting the NullException? Put the stack trace in your question

Comment: in index.java : System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",obj.path());

Comment: at config.Configuration.path :>> String url = pro.getProperty("ChromeDriverPath");

Comment: which line of your script is throwing your error?

Comment: Sometimes it's because of the spaces in the path. Try modifying `ChromeDriverPath = G:\\Selenium Webdriver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe` to `ChromeDriverPath = G:\\Selenium-Webdriver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe`, with a '-' between "Selenium" and "Webdriver" (and of course rename the folder)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a `NullPointerException` is because in the `Configuration.java` Class you have declared `Properties pro;` globally but again within the `Configuration()` constructor you have again initiated another instance of `Properties` as `Properties pro = new Properties();`. Hence the `NullPointerException`.

Change the line:

```
Properties pro = new Properties();
```

to:

```
pro = new Properties();
```

Your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Properties` from `Properties pro = new Properties();` from this code and make it:

```
pro = new Properties();
```

You already declare it above, so need to declare it again